# Robot Framework: wait for an element to (dis)appear based on a custom HTML property?

Tags: html, selenium, robotframework

I have a div with a property `panelname` that changes depending on which view in a multi step process I am in (every panel has a `Next`-button).

It takes a few seconds after each click on Next for the next panel to load and render. This div has the same `ID on` every step instead `panelname` changes for each view.

I can read the value for panelname using `Get Element Attribute` but how do I use this in one of the `Wait until page/for element`, or similar, keywords?

Answer (score 3):

The following should work, assuming you know each panel's name:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    //div[@id='sameId' and @panelname='name2']
```

This the example HTML for the keyword above:

```html
<div id="sameId" panelname="name2"></div>
```